# Suggestion for rails app to receive and process emails for trouble-tickets

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

We have an existing old, bloated ticketing system in our IT dept and it won't be changed any time soon.  Our techs who work off-site get a lot of of the emails they receive automatically from the ticketing system.  And when they go out into the field they bring printouts of each ticket email with them so they know where to go and what to do on each job.  I want to build an app that would be primarily viewed from mobile devices that would:

1. receive email from a given email account (Gmail account)
2. parse for specific fields (Technician Name:, Ticket Description:, Phone:, etc.)
3. builds a "ticket" record based off of that email
4. There should be views for each tech to see only his own assigned tickets, and also a main "dashboard" view so all assigned requests can be views as a long list.
5. When the tech hits the "delete" on the index/dashboard it will remove the record and then send an email "reminder" back to the tech's own email address as a reminder to close the ticket in the main ticketing system when he returns back to the office.

Any suggestions how I should implement this?  I am basically building a side-app that presents better/quicker viewing for the techs when their remotely working.  I was thinking about using mailman gem to receive the emails but could not find a good step-by-step tutorial...  And wasn't sure how to handle the "email processing" portion of the project.  Please let me know if anyone has done this sort of thing or can point me in the right direction.

Comment: Take a look to this list: https://www.ruby-toolbox.com/categories/e_mail_processing

Answer (score 0):

I would use redmine.  Its written in Rails!

[RedMine](http://www.redmine.org/)